# Возможно ли 1с подружить с firebase?

Tags: firebase, 1с

Подскажите, возможно ли чтобы 1с, читала данные из realtime data firebase. Если да, где можно подробно почитать как это сделать? Необходимо создать прилу, которая будет писать в firebase, и 1с брать инфу от туда. Спасибо

Comment: Простите, не знаю что такое "realtime data firebase". Какие у неё есть интерфейсы для взаимодействия?

Comment: Если точнее, Realtime Database.

Answer (score 0):

Общий алгоритм решения задачи такой:

1. Взять пример для Visual Basic или VBA
2. Заменить CreateObject("") на СоздатьОбъект(""); остальной код адаптировать под 1С;
3. Проверить работу из внешней обработки

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Попробую )